# How to work with an interface dynamically loaded from an assembly and invoke its members

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, assemblies, pinvoke

I have got some code to load an assembly and get all types, which implement a certain interface, like this (assume asm is a valid and loaded assembly).

```
var results = from type in asm.GetTypes()
  where typeof(IServiceJob).IsAssignableFrom(type)
  select type;
```

Now I'm stuck: I need to create instances of these objects and invoke methods and properties on the object. And I need to store the references to the created objects in an array for later usage.

Comment: You haven't made it clear whether the 'methods and properties' you need to invoke are arbitary or are members of the IServiceJob interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh wow - I only [blogged about this](http://www.madprops.org/blog/linq-with-reflection-part-2/) a few days ago. Here's my method to return instances of all the types that implement a given interface:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> InstancesOf<T>() where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    return from t in type.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
           where t.IsClass
               && type.IsAssignableFrom(t)
               && t.GetConstructor(new Type[0]) != null
           select (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```

If you refactor this to accept an assembly parameter rather than using the interface's assembly, it becomes flexible enough to suit your need.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: is it possible then to invoke a constructor in such a way of there is no default empty constructor?

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance has an overload which can accept an array of objects that are passed to the ctor of the class you're instantiating, but I don't think there's any way you could use that within a single query like the one I've posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of a type with the `Activator.CreateInstance` method:-

```
IServiceJob x = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

So your code becomes:-

```
IServiceJob[] results = (from type in asm.GetTypes()
  where typeof(IServiceJob).IsAssignableFrom(type)
  select (IServiceJob)Activator.CreateInstance(type)).ToArray();
```

(Note change var to IServiceJob[] to make it clear what is being created).

Comment: Keep in mind that if the implementing type doesn't have a default ctor, this code will throw a MethodMissingException. Hence the check in my query.

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: is it possible then to invoke a constructor in such a way of there is no default empty constructor?